# Better way to use an Android x86 HAXM accelerated emulator on Windows 8 with Hyperv

Tags: android, windows, hyper-v

To my knowledge, an x86 Android emulation using Intel's Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager and Windows 8 Hyperv cannot be run concurrently at the time of this writing.

The best answer would allow them to run concurrently (probably not currently possible).

The most common workaround is to uninstall the Hyperv feature completely.  If you actually need to use Hyperv this is painful.  A better work around can be found here.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/04/14/creating-a-no-hypervisor-boot-entry.aspx .  This forces you to reboot, but at least you're not having to constantly uninstall/reinstall Hyperv.

I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require anything to be uninstalled and doesn't require a reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it will be the answer.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx

I won't mark it as answered until I actually try out the RTM bits (it's in preview now), but it's a Hypver-V based android emulator.  The first 2 pain points the blog post claims to solve with the new emulator are Slowness of other emulators and Conflict with Hyper-V on Windows.

Comment: Love the Visual studio emulator.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is good answer for you. I had similar problems with x86 emulator. I've switched to Genymotion - Google Play Services are working fine, and it's really fast + official plugins for Eclipse.

But you need to install VirtualBox (but it's free) so this shouldn't be a problem.

Genymotion site: http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to genymotion.  I'll try it out this weekend.  It's likely that it will have the same issues running at the same time as hyperv, since I believe virtualbox itself conflicts with hyperv.  However, if i'm willing to give up dynamic memory and type 1 hypervisor status, switching completely to virtual box looks like it would let me virtualize and run android emulation.

Comment: Additionally it's quite simple to install additional software with genymotion

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is temporarily disable the hyper-V with a very simple command I found. You could find the detail on the link below.

https://superuser.com/questions/519991/vmware-player-is-not-working-after-installing-hyper-v-on-windows-8-pro

Comment: If you take a look at the accepted answer, you'll note that, "Both Operations require restarting your computer."  In the question I asked for a solution that doesn't require reboot.

Comment: @KennethIto - actually it's not possible to run both at the same time because only one thing can control this resource at this time.

Comment: Yep, I was hoping for a way to disable/toggle.

Answer (score 0):

The android emulator is now supported on Hyper V (It's in preview now): Details here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/